# Timer in webpage using VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

vbs file called as Main.vbs. now I embedded it into the .html file like below:

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/vbscript">
  sub main
    const runminimized = 7
    const wait_for_end = false
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run "D:\VA\Main.vbs",runminimized, wait_for_end
  end sub
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  Please make sure that the reuired Excel sheet which you are giving me to process isn in the proper folder. And first sheet has all the required columns - missing any of them could leads the Scripts to be failed.
  <button onclick="vbscript:main" >Click here to Run</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to set a Timer which would run on the page till all the scripts to end. Is it possible to set here?

Comment: what's the use of timing, when your script will fail because of your 'onclick="vbscript:Main"'?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner What the wrong I did? Please guide me!

Comment: Why does your script throw a "type mismatch" for "Main"? What should go into an onclick handler?

Comment: I have corrected it just now,by mistake I wrote it as `Main` instead of `main`.

Comment: that's still not correct ("main" vs. "test" [=real name of the Sub]). If you don't care for your code, why should anyone?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I just corrected it!

Comment: @VBSlover, if you want to interact with the user while your script runs, you must not wait till it is done, so change wait_for_end to dont_wait_for_end in both uses but keep the False, actually since it are constants you should all uppercase so DONT_WAIT_FOR_END

Comment: but what are the differences between `DONT_WAIT_FOR_END and wait_for_end`?

Comment: @peter any clock can I add there?

Answer (score 0):

I made a little mistake in my previous answer, if you want to wait for the end of the script the value of wait_for_end must be True, so no need for a timer. The post-processing can be put right after the WshShell.Run
I f you need a timer in a web-script you can use  Window.setTimeout, the sleep from vbscript won't work.
See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp for more information.

You made an error yourself in the script above, if your script is called test, your button event must be vbscript:test, or you have to rename the sub to main

In case it is a progressbar you need, tha is not easy to implement in vbscript, the best example i have seen is here http://www.northatlantawebdesign.com/index.php/2009/07/16/simple-vbscript-progress-bar/

But showing exactly how your script progresses isn't gonna be easy if you don't know the time it takes in advance, normally you should split your process in segments and update the bar with each step.

Comment: I want a time to show up the users to see how long it is taking to complete the full activity,That's it!

Comment: That is not a timer but a progressbar, is that what you need ? You will have to know the time your script takec in advance or else implement the progressbar in your vba-code

Comment: Yes, I am looking for that! but i didn't implement it in VBA ;all in vbscript I have implemented.

Comment: See my edit, but you have come to a point where i would advise taking another language in consideration, certainly if you are new to vbscript

Comment: any good idea you would like to suggest here instead a progress bar - not count down but count up might be Ok!

Comment: best way, since it's vba is showing the action in Excel itqself so the user sees what is happening, not only he will have a notion as how far the action is, he will have something to keep him occupied while waiting